# Divinity Original Sin EE: Exiting the tutorial dungeon

Tags: divinity-original-sin

Just started out with DOS:Enhanced Edition and almost finished the tutorial dungeon.

After beating Ragequin I go up the stairs and find a locked gate.
How do I open it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be a key where you killed Ragequin.

Comment: Yes. I found it after learning that "alt" activates the 'items on ground' display.